# Replacing lines via boost regex with boost for relatively complex regex

Tags: c++, regex, string, boost

## Background

I'm looking to replace replace all lines from a file that start with **`--`** or with **`[[:space:]]{1,}`**. Broadly speaking, I'm looking to achieve the results that would be similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11321705/1655567).

## Code

```
/*
 * so_question.cpp
 * Read text files and remove all lines starting with -- or <space>*--
 * Clean text is passed to cout.
 * 
 * Compile and test:
 * clang++ -lboost_regex -Wall -std=c++11 so_question.cpp -o so_question && ./so_question tst.sql
 */


#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/replace.hpp>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    // Read file to stringstream
    std::ifstream file( argv[1] );

    if ( file )
    {
        std::stringstream buffer;

        buffer << file.rdbuf();

        file.close();

        // Create a string variable to apply boost::regex
        std::string readText;
        readText = buffer.str();

        // Regular expression finding comments
        boost::regex re_comment("^([[:space:]]{1,}|)--.*(\n|\r|)$");

        // Replace desired lines
        // boost::replace_all(readText, re_comment, " ");

        // Replace via regex replace
        std::string result = boost::regex_replace(readText, re_comment, " ");

       // Show clean text when using regex_replace
       std::cout << "\nClean text:\n" << result << std::endl;

        // Show clean text
        // std::cout << "Clean text:" << readText << std::endl;


        return 0;
    }

}
```

### Test data

```
-- Query taken from:
-- https://stackoverflow.com/a/12467388/1655567
SELECT country.name as country, country.headofstate
from country
    -- Worst place to add comment ever
  -- Here is even uglier
inner join city on city.id = country.capital
where city.population > 100000
-- this comment makes no sense here and would break sql parser buyt hey
and country.headofstate like 'A%'
-- WOW!
```

#### Desired results

```
SELECT country.name as country, country.headofstate
from country
inner join city on city.id = country.capital
where city.population > 100000
and country.headofstate like 'A%'
```

### Compilation and test

```
clang++ -lboost_regex -Wall -std=c++11 so_question.cpp -o so_question && ./so_question tst.sql
```

## Problem

The returned text is exactly the same as in the provided file. I reckon that the problem is with the particular regex syntax I'm using. However, after reading [boost regex documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_31_0/libs/regex/doc/syntax.html) and testing [multiple versions](https://regex101.com/r/MOx6t4/5) of that regex it's not clear to me what the right syntax should be.

- [ALE](https://github.com/w0rp/ale) points out that `#includes` are not sorted properly. Considering [llvm guidelines](http://llvm.org/docs/CodingStandards.html#include-style) what would be the right order *(this is side point, not related to main question)*?

Comment: Could you check if you have misplaced `|` alternation symbol ? My first guess is you did and it should had been outside capturing group i.e after `)`

Comment: @Rahul Thanks for your comment. I'll have a look, in effect I was looking for something on the lines of `(\n|\r|\z)` so all line breaks and string end. I reckon that `\z` does not work in boost but I'll look into **`|`**.

Comment: To check beginning with `--` you don't have to check rest of the line with `.*(\n|\r|)$`. Only `^--` would be suffice.

Comment: @Rahul Fair point, I also want to capture any spaces before `--`, would `[[:space:]]*--` work?

Comment: Since you are checking for more than one spaces, ` --` will be covered in same condition. I have devised [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/m0rIjK/1/) for your understanding.

Comment: Do you need to keep the lines with `--` in? Because you could read the file one line at a time and just ignore any lines that match for `^\s*--` (or even just use normal string operations to detect them)?

Comment: You're compiling c++11. Why not use `std::regex`?

Answer (score 1):

Rearrange your parentheses:

```
(?m)^(?:--|[[:space:]]+).+
```

And [**see a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/DxhW7y/2/). Note that `[[:space:]]{1,}` is the same as `[[:space:]]+`.

Comment: I've tried the syntax: `boost::regex re_comment("(?m)^(?:--|[[:space:]]+).+");` and the getting the results: `  std::string result = boost::regex_replace(readText, re_comment, " ");` but I keep on getting empty line when running: `std::cout << "\nClean text:\n" << result << std::endl;`

Answer (score 0):

The form of regex_replace that you call returns the string with replacements, it does not operate in-place.

Comment: I've changed `boost::regex_replace` to: `std::string result = boost::regex_replace(readText, re_comment, " ");`